Is there a way to make each key stroke be a hard once per stroke, AHK
I dont code at all so take this as making a good action, im running a regedit macro for a game and it conflicts with my autohotkey script, as in macro i mean multiple and faster inputs for each key stroke, so it makes it easy to miss the hotkeys, as the key starts repeating itself if i press it for "too long". I want to know if there's a way to make to make each hotkey a hard once per stroke if that makes any sense, so even if i hold it it doesnt start repeating itself.
5::sendinput 2zzz
capslock::sendinput 2xxxx
An example of the ahk script
As i said i dont know how to code.

The simplest way to do this would be by using KeyWait.
5::
    SendInput 2
    KeyWait 5
Return

CapsLock::
    SendInput 2
    KeyWait CapsLock
Return

However, you'll quickly run into threading problems. To see this in action, using this example, press and hold 5, then press and hold CapsLock, then release 5 and try pressing it again. It'll no longer send 2 (that is, the 5 hotkey will fail to trigger because CapsLock hotkey's KeyWait has effectively overridden its own). Similarly, if #MaxThreadsPerHotkey is configured to anything but 1, each hotkey, when held, will trigger that many times before stopping.
Therefore, a better way would be to keep track of what key has been pressed in a shared object (source). Here's how that would look:
5::
    PreventRepeating()
    SendInput 2
Return

CapsLock::
    PreventRepeating()
    SendInput 2
Return

PreventRepeating()
{
    Static PrevRep := Object()
    If PrevRep[A_ThisHotkey]
        Exit
    If InStr(A_ThisHotkey,"Up")
    {
        PrevRep[SubStr(A_ThisHotkey,1,-3)] := False
        Exit
    }
    PrevRep[A_ThisHotkey] := True
    Hotkey %A_ThisHotkey%%A_Space%Up,%A_ThisHotkey%
}


